# Allow the user to modify some parameters from .env Symfony

Tags: symfony, environment-variables, symfony4

I have some config variables on the .env file. I want to create a page on my web application to allow the administrators to modify the value of some .env variables (for example the mail configured to send mails). For this purpose, I have:

```
MAILER_SENDER_ADDRESS=backoffice@example.com
MAILER_SENDER_NAME="Application Name"
MAILER_URL=gmail://firstname.lastname@gmail.com:ijfxxiencrrdqihe@localhost
```

I am able to read the current values on my controller but I don't know how to save back the values filled by the user on my form.

Please, any help would be really apreciated.

Comment: ENV variables aren't supposed to be changed on fly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables are there to help you specify variables for the particular environment your application runs on, for example you could have your app sitting locally on your computer which you develop on, and you could have it in the cloud running the production version of your app, version which will actually send emails correctly using real data.

What you need to do is have somewhere to store the settings you let your users customise, for example in a database. When it comes to sending the emails, you will then have to do the following:

```
$message = (new Swift_Message())
->setFrom(['john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'])
...
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am going to save the values of the .env file to the database, to allow modifying them. It will be a boring process to modify all the references to $_ENV in my code, but I need that the user can edit some values.